# A puzzle related to nested loops

Tags: loops, time, for-loop, nested-loops

For a given input N, how many times does the enclosed statement executes?

```
for i in 1 … N loop
  for j in 1 … i loop
    for k in 1 … j loop
      sum = sum + i ;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end loop;
```

Can anyone figure out an easy way or a formula to do this in general. Please explain.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rhys For programs like this, every time you need to go through the entire program or write a dry run table to calculate the number of times the enclosed statement executes. But is there a general way to figure this out, by just looking at the conditions of the for-loops?

Comment: Adding very similar question link: ["Nested loops result"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019807/nested-loops-result?lq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- First, I written a `C` code to generate sum:

> ```
> int main(){
>   int i =0, k =0, j =0, n =0;
>   int N =0; 
>   int sum =0;
>   N =10;
>   for (n=1; n <= N; n++){
>   // unindented code here
>   sum =0;
>   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
>       for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
>           for (k=1; k<=j; k++)
>               sum++;
>
>   printf("\n N=%d  sum = %d",n, sum); 
>   }
>   printf("\n");
> }
> ```

- Simple compile and generate result for `N=1 to N=10` :

`$ gcc sum.c`
`$ ./a.out`

```
 N=1  sum = 1
 N=2  sum = 4
 N=3  sum = 10
 N=4  sum = 20
 N=5  sum = 35
 N=6  sum = 56
 N=7  sum = 84
 N=8  sum = 120
 N=9  sum = 165
 N=10  sum = 220
```

- Then, Tried to explore `How this works?` with some diagrams:

  For, `N=1`:

> ```
> i<=N,     (i=1)       
>             |
> j<=i,     (j=1)       
>             |
> k<=j,     (K=1)       
>             |
> sum=0.    sum++       ---> sum = 1
> ```

That is     (1) = 1

For, `N=2`:

> ```
> i<=N,     (i=1)-------(i=2)
>             |     |-----|-----|
> j<=i,     (j=1) (j=1)      (j=2)
>             |     |     |----|----|
> k<=j,     (K=1) (K=1) (K=1)    (K=2)               
>             |     |     |        |    
> sum=0,    sum++  sum++ sum++   sum++  --> sum = 4
> ```

That is     (1)  +  (1  +      2)       =  4

For, `N=3`:

> ```
> i<=N,     (i=1)-------(i=2)--------------------(i=3)
>             |     |-----|-----|        |---------|-------------|
> j<=i,     (j=1) (j=1)      (j=2)     (j=1)      (j=2)        (j=3)
>             |     |     |----|----|    |     |----|----|    |-----|-----|
> k<=j,     (K=1) (K=1) (K=1)    (K=2) (K=1) (K=1)    (K=2) (K=1) (K=2) (K=3)
>             |     |     |        |     |     |        |     |     |        |
> sum=0,    sum++  sum++ sum++  sum++ sum++  sum++    sum++  sum++ sum++  sum++
>             --> sum = 10
> ```

That is    (1)  + (1 +      2)    +  ( 1  +       2       +          3 )  = 10

```
N = 1, (1)    = 1                                           

N = 2, (1) + (1 + 2)    = 4

N = 3, (1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3)  = 10

N = 4, (1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)  = 20

N = 5, (1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)  = 35
```

Finally, I could understood that sum of `N`  in three loop is:

(1) + (sum 0f 1 to 2) + ... + (sum of 1 to (N-2)) + (sum of 1 to (N-1) ) + (sum of 1 to N)

or we can write it as:

=> (1) + (1 + 2) + ...+ (1 + 2 +....+ i) + ... + (1 + 2 + ....+ N-1) + (1 + 2 + ....+ N)

=> ( N * 1 ) + ( (N-1) * 2) + ( (N-2) * 3) +...+ ( (N -i+1) * i ) +... + ( 1 * N)

You can refer here for simplification calculations: [(I asked **HERE** )](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247150/how-to-simplify-this-equation)
[image]

[**YOUR ANSWER**]

`= ( ((N) * (N+1) * (N+2)) / 6 )`

And, I think its correct. I checked as follows:

```
N = 1,    (1 * 2 * 3)/6  = 1

N = 2,    (2 * 3 * 4)/6 = 4

N = 3,    (3 * 4 * 5)/6 = 6

N = 4,    (4 * 5 * 6)/6 = 10

N = 5,    (5 * 6 * 7)/6 = 35
```

Also, The complexity of this algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>)

**EDIT**:

The following loop also has same numbers of count, that is `= ( ((N) * (N+1) * (N+2)) / 6 )`

```
for i in 1 … N loop
  for j in i … N loop
    for k in j … N loop
      sum = sum + i ;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end loop;
```