# How to write summation expression in HTML?

Tags: html, web

How to write equivalent HTML expression for following Latex:

```
$$\sum_{k=1}^Nk(N-k+1)
```

The image is:

[image]

I did like this:

```
∑ <sub>k=1</sub> <sup>N</sup>
```

but output is like this

∑ <sub>k=1</sub> <sup>N</sup>

I am not good at HTML and I searched on web but couldn't find answer. 
Please help on this..Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need it for a lot of stuff in your project you'll probably find [**MathJax**](http://www.mathjax.org/) useful. Otherwise if you need just this one formula then try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7XEy/1/)

```
<p>
    <span>&Sigma;</span>
    k ( N - k + 1 )
</p>​
```

***CSS***

```
p {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

span {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: .7em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span:before {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "N";
    width: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

span:after {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "k = 1";
    width: 27px;
    text-align: center;
}
​
```

Comment: @Zolthan Toth : Although it working for .html...but how to write if I need to [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284#13622284) on stackoverflow. at the end I have to upload an image.

Comment: Some day back I need to write this kind of expression while answering on stackoverflow but I couldn't write. After your answer I could write on for my html pase ..How to write this expression in stackoverflow's answer form.

Comment: Here is [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284#13622284) where I wanted to write an `summation expression`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, you can't do custom CSS on SO. The image will suffice for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is almost certainly the correct answer (there is even an example of a summation on the homepage), you can use simple HTML elements (however these won't look as good as the final MathJax/LaTeX results).

The summation sign is HTML entity `&sum;` and the super- and sub-scripts can be marked up with the `sup` and `sub` elements, so try:

```
&sum;<sub>k=1</sub><sup>N</sup> k (N - k + 1)
```

to get: ∑<sub>k=1</sub><sup>N</sup> k (N - k + 1) .

Answer (score 1):

Use **Mathjax**: http://www.mathjax.org/

It is built specifically for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, the best option is probably [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), though perhaps the lightweight [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) might suit some needs better. Here’s how to use MathJax for your formula (for production use, consider uploading the MathJax software onto your own server):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>MathJax demo</title>
<script src=
"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
$$\sum_{k=1}^Nk(N-k+1)$$
```

Pure HTML won’t take you very far, and even with CSS styling, the results are unsatisfactory for display formulas. You would need to use CSS positioning (which would get tricky here) or a clumsy table-based construct in HTML; cf. to my notes [Math in HTML (and CSS)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/), especially the notes on two-dimensionality at the end.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).