# How can you render summation symbols in HTML code?

Tags: html, unicode

When I try to render a summation expression in HTML code with

```html
&sum;<sub>n=1</sub><sup>&infin;</sup>
```

the superscript infinity symbol is not over the summation symbol, or even close.  I know there are "combining" symbols but can't find one that would help here.  And as far as I can tell there are no negative-space characters.

Comment: Hmm, it is for me. Try using a different font.

Comment: Take a look at [How to write summation expression in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626132/how-to-write-summation-expression-in-html)