# complexity of two dependent for loops with outer loop of log n complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

**The problem**

Compute the complexity of this algorithm:

```
 for(i=n; i>1;i=i/2)
   for(j=i;j<n;j++){
         statement;
   }
```

**What have I done on this topic before:**

The first loop runs logn times.
The second loop runs n-i times with i starting from n and changing to i/2 in each outer loop iteration. So the inner loop runs like this:

```
n-n                             0 times

n - n/2                        n/2 times

n - n/4                        3n/4 times

n - n/8                        7n/8 times

n - n/16                     15n/16 times
```

and so on till

`n - 1` times

so the general term is `n * ((2^n)-1)/(2^n)`

Now this sequence is not arithmetic nor geometric. So formula of `n/2 * (a+l)` cannot be applied on it. How do I further proceed with this solution or if it is wrong, then what is the correct method.

Note: If `n/2*(a+l)` is applied, the resulting complexity is `-n/(2^n) = O(2^n).`

Comment: Read: [what is value of x in term of n?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723875/what-is-value-of-x-in-term-of-n?lq=1)

Comment: There is no x. Do you mean O(x)?

Comment: As `n` becomes bigger, the general term approaches `n`. Maybe that is a solution.

Comment: No `x` I mean read linked question and Try like this: [A puzzle related to nested loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284#13622284)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track. As you mentioned, the inner loop would run `log n` times. So, the total number of times it runs is:

```
    (n - n/2) + (n - n/4) + ... (log n) times
  = n*(log n) - (n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... up to 1)
  = n*(log n) - n*(1/2 + 1/4 + ...)
 <= n*(log n) - n because (1/2 + 1/4 + ...) is 1 even if we take all terms till infinity (G.P)
  = n(log n - 1), which is O(n*log(n))
```

Remember that when calculating complexity, you are always looking for upper bounds, not exact numbers.

Comment: How did you get logn times in the first step?

Comment: Since the outer loop will run `log n` times... Also, `(n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + up to 1)` will have to be log n times since the number of terms will be equal to the number of powers of `2`. Got it?

Comment: Yes :)  the last time inner loop will run its i will be equal to logn!

Comment: @HariShankar How did you arrive at the terms `(n-n/2), (n-n/4)` etc in the first step?

Comment: @HariShankar Your second sentence says "the inner loop would run log n times"..Shouldn't it be the *outer* loop and not *inner* loop? What am I missing?

Comment: @HariShankar Because the inner loop runs n-i times and at first i is n so the inner loop runs n-n times. Then control goes to increment step and i is divided by 2 so i is n/2... Then inner loop runs n-n/2 times(putting in general term n-i), and so on

Comment: @HariShankarAnd these terms are added together to get the total number of times the statement is run.

Comment: @HariShankarSo... It should be n - logn the last time the inner loop is run? :)

Comment: @Geek I think user2223421 answered your questions but tagged me instead by mistake. So after user's explanation, is it clear now?

Comment: @HariShankar Yes it is clear now..I was reading the inner loop as `for(j=1;j<n;j++)` instead of `for(j=i;j<n;j++)`...Hence I was confused. My bad.... Anyway +1 for your answer.

Comment: @HariShankar Can you please explain your second step? I am confused how logn *n came out of the brackets

Comment: @user2223421 `(n - a1) + (n - a2) + (n - a3)... 10 times = 10*n - (a1 + a2 + a3 + .. + a10)`, right? Same way, here 10 is replaced by `log n`.

Answer (score 5):

First the calculations

```
A := (n - n)  + (n - n/2) + (n - n/4)  + ... + (n - n / 2^logn) = 
     log n * (n) - n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + .... 1 / 2 ^ logn)
A > log n * (n)  - n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + .... + 1 / 2^infity) =
     logn * n - n = n(logn - 2)
A < log n * (n)
```

As you see I have assigned the expression you want to evaluate to `A`. From the last two inequations it follows the complexity of your algorithm is `thetha(n logn)`

Here I used the well known geometric progression of `(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + .....) = 2`

Comment: How did you get the term n - n/2^logn in the first step? :)

Comment: Got it! Statement under outer loop does not run on n-1 times because the comparison i>1 will be false! So it will run one iteration before that times which is n-2^logn times!

Comment: How did you get logn * n in the second step and subtract it from the series?

Comment: @user2223421 look at the first step: how many terms you have? `log n`. Each one of them is carrying a value of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The exact no of times the statement runs is
nlogn - 2n(1-1/2^logn)

Comment: Can you explain how you got this conclusion?