# Big O Time Complexity for this code

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, pseudocode

Given the following code -:

```c
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= N; j = j+i)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

I know that the outer loop runs `N` times, and that the inner loop runs approximately `log(N)` times. This is because on each iteration of `i`, `j` runs `ceil(N)`, `ceil(N/2)`, `ceil(N/4)` times and so on. This is just a rough calculation through which one can guess that the time complexity will definitely be `O(N log(N))`.

How would I mathematically prove the same?

I know that for the `ith` iteration, `j` increments by `ceil(N/2(i - 1))`.

Comment: you may like to use the approach I used in myanswer: [A puzzle related to nested loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284#13622284) but it take time.

Comment: @Alp j grows by i each iteration, not by 1.

Comment: Not sure but it mat be helpful: [what is value of x in term of n?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723875/what-is-value-of-x-in-term-of-n?lq=1) And Here is [one more question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932387/complexity-of-two-dependent-for-loops-with-outer-loop-of-logn-complexity?lq=1)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: The example is nice but I was looking for a proper mathematical proof, where I would apply the `log` to base 2.

Comment: Perhaps I am thinking of iterative recurrence solving, which obviously cannot be applied here.

Comment: @TheRedBlackTree I am glad that you get an answer, good luck.. :) (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of iterations of the inner loop for each value of i will be

```
i = 1: j = 1, 2, 3 ..., n ---> total iterations = n
i = 2: j = 1, 3, 5 ..., n ---> total iterations = n/2 if 2 divides n or one less otherwise
i = 3: j = 1, 4, 7 ..., n ---> total iterations = n/3 if 3 divides n or one less otherwise
...
i = m: j = 1, 1 + m, ... , n ---> total iterations ~ n/m
...
1
```

So approximately the total iterations will be `(n + n/2 + n/3 ... + 1)`.

[image]

That sum is the [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) which has value approximately `ln(n) + C` so the total iterations is approximately `n ln(n)` and since all logarithms are related by a constant, the iterations will be `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: @TheRedBlackTree You're right, n(n + ... + 1) too much.  Thanks for catching that!