# Java Code Complexity

Tags: java, complexity-theory

```
int n=3;
int sum = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= i; j = j - 2) {  
        sum = i + j;  
        System.out.println(sum);  
    }  
}
```

i've been trying to find the complexity of this code (O(?) etc)
any ideas?

Comment: Homework? If so, please tag as such.

Comment: `O(n2)` .. you need to understand Big O, it can be even said `O(n3)` or `O(n4)`.

Comment: @pajton [Homework tag is now deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: i'm sortta lost inside the nested loop  is it a sequence or something?

Comment: Read [A puzzle related to nested loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284#13622284) To get some idea how to solve it.

Comment: @vidit ah, I didn't know! I am returning to SO after quite of break:)

Comment: Maybe this will help a little: [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/1393766).

Comment: @pajton Actually, [the homework tag is now officially depricated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain just to clear my own understanding. The first loop run `n` times. Now, let's discuss the inner loop.

First iteration, it will run from `n-1` to `0` inclusive, with increments of 2, resulting in `n/2` iterations. Second Iteration, it will run from `n-1` to `1` inclusive, with increments of 2, resulting in `(n-1)/2` iterations. And so on, the last iteration will be from `n-1` to `n-1` inclusive, and it will be `1` iteration.

Counting all iterations, it will be `[n/2 + (n-1)/2 + .... 1] ≈ n2`

Comment: I think you mean `n^2` but not `n2` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan- Yes sir, please feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, constant, for the fixed n... :-) But if you want a complexity in n, it's O(n^2) - it would be o(n^2) if the inner cycle went from n to 0, but as it is, we only reduce the time in half by ending at i (imagine a square; the area where j >= i is a triangle), and by another half by stepping j by 2, which together is just a constant multiplicative factor 1/4 (IOW not changing the asymptotic complexity).