# Time complexity of this specific algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Forgive me if what I'm about to ask is obvious, but I've been thinking about it for 2 hours now! I just can't figure it out....

Well, I had something similar to this :

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
```

I can certainly say that the complexity is O(N+(N-1)+(N-2)...), but is there a simpler notation for this type?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284#13622284) it covers your answer. it is n^2

Comment: sum from n to 1 is n*(n+1)/2 which is O(n*n) because o(1/2) is just constant

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

First interaction: 1 execution of the command line

Second interaction: 2 executions of the command line

...

Nth interaction: N executions of the command line

= sum 1 + ... N= sum of arithmetic progression=(N/2)(1+N)

Therefore, O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

sum from one to n equals to n(n+1)/2=n*n/2+1/2 in therms of asymptotic notation it is O(n^2)
the rest should be clear I guess