# Algorithmic complexity of naive code for processing all consecutive subsequences of a list: n^2 or n^3?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm studying for a test and found this question:

I can't really determine the complexity, I figured it's either O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n<sup>3</sup>) and I'm leaning towards O(n<sup>3</sup>).
Can someone tell me what it is and why?

My idea that it's O(n<sup>2</sup>) is because in the `j` loop, `j = i` which gives a triangle shape, and then the `k` loop goes from `i + 1` to `j`, which I think is the other half of the triangle.

```
public static int what(int[] arr)
{
    int m = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            int s = arr[i];
            for (int k=i+1; k<=j; k++)
             s += arr[k];
            if (s > m)
             m = s;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Also if you can tell me what it does?

I figured it returns the addition of positive integers or the biggest integer in the array.
But for arrays like `{99, -3, 0, 1}` it returns `99`, which I think is because it's buggy. If not than I have no Idea what it does:

```
{99, 1} => returns 100
{-1, -2, -3} => return -1
{-1, 5, -2} => returns 5
{99, -3, 0, 1} => returns 99 ???
```

Comment: I think this may be solvable in O(n)

Comment: This sounds like a homework question you need to do yourself.

Comment: Its looks like O^3 to me. I solved similar code: [A puzzle related to nested loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622284/1673391) I think your code matches with edit code in my answer.

Comment: For your reference, the problem is called ["Maximum subarray sum"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Comment: I would argue that you already get Ω(n^3) work for the cases i<n/3, j>2n/3 and the total work is O(n^3), instead of bothering to try and work out summations.

Comment: Geometry to the rescue: if i, j and k are spatial axes, then you are drawing a triangular pyramid (where each "point" or "cell" is a triplet with distinct i, j and k, reached in the inner loop only once). Area of such a pyramid of side n is n^3  / 6. Since constant factors (1/6) get discarded in big-oh notation, this is O(n^3)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can proceed methodically, using Sigma Notation, to obtain the order of growth complexity:

[image]

Comment: +1, And this is why I'm sad that many universities drop the engineering math requirement for a CS degree...

Comment: Well, I made a personal effort to re-conquer mathematics through concrete cases (the realm of algorithms). However, I needed a methodology, and I ran into some documents that increased my curiosity about Sigma Notation. Mark Allen Weiss's Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis Book (3rd edition), in Chapter 1 or 2 (Maximum Subsequence Problem): a case with several sigmas. These documents were very helpful too: [Jauhar](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt) and [Nels](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~sbtajali/2002/slides/01%20Analysis%20of%20Algorithms.pdf)

Comment: I came out an EE+CS major. So I had to go through all the advanced math that none of my CS-only buddies had to even touch... While I haven't retained much of that math, I'm glad I still learned it at some point. At least I know where to look when I need it.

Comment: I've double-checked this down to the second-to-last line (at which point the `O(n^3)` is already clearly identified) and I also confirm there's no mistakes!  It's interesting to note that the constant factor in front of the relevant `n^3` term is `1/12`, as opposed to the typical `1/2` for an `O(n^2)` algorithm that forms every possible pair from a sequence and performs a calculation on the pair.  I.e., the third sum in the OP's question - from `i` to `j` - brings in the added `1/6` to the constant factor, implying that this subsequence is on average `1/6`'th the length of the sequence.

Answer (score 15):

You have 3 for statements. For large `n`, it is quite obvious that is `O(n^3)`. `i` and `j` have `O(n)` each, `k` is a little shorter, but still `O(n).`

The algorithm returns the biggest sum of consecutive terms. That's why for the last one it returns 99, even if you have 0 and 1, you also have -3 that will drop your sum to a maximum 97.

PS: Triangle shape means `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1) / 2 = O(n^2)`

Comment: no I checked {-1,5,3,-2,2} <- you are right it returns 8 (consecutive). but then I checked {-1,5,3,-2,2,1} <- now it returns 9, biggest consecutive is still 8 no?

Comment: No, 9 is correct. It will pick 5, 3, -2, 2 and 1. It doesn't have to start from beginning.

Answer (score 9):

**Code:**

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) // Loop A
{
    for (int j=i; j<arr.length;j++) // Loop B
    {
        for (int k=i+1; k<=j; k++) // Loop C
        {
            // ..
        }
    }
}
```

**Asymptotic Analysis on Big-O:**

```
Loop A: Time = 1 + 1 + 1 + .. 1 (n times) = n

Loop B+C: Time = 1 + 2 + 3 + .. + m = m(m+1)/2

Time = SUM { m(m+1)/2 | m in (n,0] }

Time < n * (n(n+1)/2) = 1/2 n^2 * (n+1) = 1/2 n^3 + 1/2 n^2

Time ~ O(n^3)
```

Comment: It is not really correct. B+C is not n(n+1)/2 because j starts with i. Without computing a result, I think that n(n-1) / 2 is more accurate. Of course, in terms of big oh, it is irrelevant.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I was using an upper bound, fixed post :)

Answer (score 3):

No matter triangle shape or not, it always a complexity O(N^3), but of course with lower constant then a full triple nested cycles.

Answer (score 3):

You can model the running time of the function as

```
sum(sum(sum(Theta(1), k=i+1..j),j=i..n),i=1..n)
```

As

```
sum(sum(sum(1, k=i+1..j),j=i..n),i=1..n) = 1/6 n^3  - 1/6 n,
```

the running time is Theta(n^3).

Answer (score 3):

O(n^3).

You have calculated **any two item between arr[0] and arr[arr.length - 1]**, running by "i" and "j", which means C(n,2), that is n*(n + 1)/2 times calculation.

And the **average step** between each calculation running by "k" is (0 + arr.length)/2, so the total calculation times is C(n, 2) * arr.length / 2 = n * n *(n + 1) / 4, that is O(n^3).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not feel well-versed enough in the underlying theory to directly apply @MohamedEnnahdiElIdri's analysis, why not simply start by testing the code?

Note first that the loop boundaries only depend on the array's length, not its content, so regarding the time complexity, it does not matter what the algorithm does. You might as well analyse the time complexity of

```
public static long countwhat(int length) {
  long count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < length; j++) {
      for (int k = i + 1; k <= j; k++) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Looking at this, is it easier to derive a hypothesis? If not, simply test whether the return value is proportional to `length` squared or `length` cubed...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int l = 1; l <= 10000; l *= 2) {
    long count = countwhat(l);
    System.out.println("i=" + l + ", #iterations:" + count + 
      ", #it/n²:" + (double) count / l / l +
      ", #it/n³:" + (double) count /  l / l / l);
  }
}
```

... and notice how one value does not approach anyconstant with rising `l` and the other one does (not incidentally the very same constant associated with the highest power of $n$ in the methodological analysis).

Comment: A silly idea. Complexity (of something like this) is not difficult to figure out, and testing small values of `n` is completely counter to the mathematical idea.

Comment: @jwg "not difficult" for you and me, maybe. But for the OP? Why did they ask, then? And "small values"? The OP is not asking about some abstract algorithm, but a specific method running on a limited-memory machine (the actual input is an int array, mind you). Also, the values are sure enough to discard the idea of "triangle shape, and then [...] the other half of the triangle" leading to O(n²).

Comment: Why did they ask? Good question. They asked because they are studying for a test (as stated in the first line of the question). The question  is an exercise. Clearly this makes your solution even more silly than if it were a practical problem.

Comment: @jwg that's ridiculous. This is exactly the way you solve a math problem, not, as you propose, by already knowing how to do it. If you asked me to find a general formula as a function of a number n, I would start by working it out for n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6; and if I had a computer I might go as high as 10,000 and see what it is.

Comment: @djechlin And when you'd finished doing that, you could start using mathematics to find the answer, which you have to do anyway.

Comment: @jwg you *start* using mathematics when you figure out a programmatic test to do. That's what math is. See e.g. Polya *How To Solve It*. That's why this is a good answer.

Comment: No, math is the science of *not* going the long way around.

Answer (score 3):

This requires `O(n^3)` time due to the fact that in the three loops, *three distinct variables are incremented*. That is, when one inside loop is over, it does not affect the outer loop. The outer loop runs as many times it was to run before the inner loop was entered.

And this is the maximum contiguous subarray sum problem. Self-explanatory when you see the example:

```
{99, 1} => returns 100
{-1, -2, -3} => return -1
{-1, 5, -2} => returns 5
{99, -3, 0, 1} => returns 99
```

There is an excellent algorithm known as Kadane's algorithm (do google for it) which solves this in `O(n)` time.

Here it goes:

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

Loop for each element of the array
  (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
  (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0
  (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
return max_so_far
```

References: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), [2](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622284/1519469).

Answer (score 2):

The complete reasoning is as follows:

Let `n` be the length of the array.

1) There are three nested loops.

2) The innermost loop performs exactly `j-i` iterations (`k` running from `i+1` to `j` inclusive). There is no premature exit from this loop.

3) The middle loop performs exactly `n-j` iterations (`j` running from `i` to `n-1` inclusive), each involving `j-i` innermost iterations, in total `(i-i)+(i+1-i)+(i+2-i)+... (n-1-i) = 0+1+2... + (n-1-i)`. There is no premature exit from this loop.

4) The outermost loop performs exactly `n` iterations (`i` running from `0` to `n-1` inclusive), each involving `0+1+2+ ... (n-1-i)` innermost iterations. In total, `(0+1+2... n-1) + (0+1+2+... n-2) + (0+1+2+... n-3) + ... (0)`. There is no premature exit from this loop.

Now how do handle handle this mess ? You need to know a little about the Faulhaber's formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). In a nutshell, it says that the sum of integers up to `n` is `O(n^2)`; and the sum of the sum of integers up to `n` is `O(n^3)`, and so on.

If you recall from calculus, the primitive of `X` is `X^2/2`; and the primitive of `X^2` is `X^3/3`. Every time the degree increases. This is not by coincidence.

Your code runs in `O(n^3)`.