# How to Perform Algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, logging, big-o, analysis

I have the following algorithm and need to conduct a Big O analysis on it. I'm very new to this topic but I understand O(1), O(n), O(n<sup>2</sup>)..O(log n) and O(n log n).

How would I analyze the following algorithm?

```
x <== 1
for i = 1 to n
    for j = i to 1 (decrement)
        x <== x + 1
```

Comment: check: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622284/1673391 "edit" part, similar trick you can apply.

Comment: @Grijesh yea, i see that…but would the decrementation make a difference or is the run time in this case also O(n^3) as well

Comment: yes, draw trees .. I think you will get mirror images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each execution of the inner loop: `for j = i to 1`, it will run i steps, with i from 1 to n.

So the total time complexity is

```
1 + 2 + ... + n = n*(n+1)/2 ~ O(n^2)
```